# Importing Modules using React and VS Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, module, compiler-errors

I am using React in VS code, and I am trying to import the following modules:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
```

I am able to successfully import React, but when I import `axios`, I get a Module not found error.

./src/components/UploadForm.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'axios' in '/Users/jsmith/upload-file/upload-file/src/components'

My program fails to compile, and I am not sure how to fix this. This happens for a few other modules as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have forgotten to install the axios package, if so, run below command.

```
npm install axios
```

Answer (score 0):

You first have to install axios

```
yarn add axios
```

then you import

```
import axios from 'axios';
```